# Multisite wordpress $user->roles is empty, $wp_roles->roles is empty...?

Tags: php, wordpress, roles, multisite

On a Wordpress Multisite logging in as three different users with three different roles: superadmin, subscriber, and a new custom role "school_contact" - upon login I want to redirect them to a different location depending on their role. So we have a working plugin that handles login redirection already, but now I want to detect the user role and send it to a different location based on that role.

Problem is, $user->roles is returning an **empty array** like [] for my users, except for the one subscriber user.

Upon further investigation, $wp_roles->roles is returning null.

Here's my code:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );

function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    AssistanceLeagueController::writeTolog("Login detected. Current user roles: " . json_encode($user->roles)); //prints []
    AssistanceLeagueController::writeTolog("All Roles: " . json_encode($wp_roles->roles)); // prints null
}
```

It's the same result for both superadmin and School Contact.

I've tried using `$user = wp_get_current_user();` but then my user didn't return anything. I think this is because I'm attaching to the very beginning of the login process and the user hasn't technically logged in yet.

**A little more info**
When I output json_encode($user) for the superadmin I get this:

```
{"data":{"ID":"19782","user_login":"optewebdev","user_pass":"$P$BgY8wrhUKPuB9venGB                          XqRDAXz58coL0","user_nicename":"optewebdev","user_email":"david@opteweb.c                          om","user_url":"http:\/\/www.opteweb.com","user_registered":"2015-12-12 0                          1:01:13","user_activation_key":"1513759265:$P$BrkXfIXahs9QknsztysSAl19Ej9                          udy1","user_status":"0","display_name":"optewebdev","spam":"0","deleted":                          "0"},"ID":19782,"caps":{"manage_signup_sheets":true},"cap_key":"wp_capabi                          lities","roles":[],"allcaps":{"manage_signup_sheets":true},"filter":null}
```

When I output json_encode($user) for the superadmin I get this:

```
{"data":{"ID":"26945","user_login":"schoolcontact-test","user_pass":"$P$BmMrcYf.fxTI0mZM3ZkKiV9KB.GUbF.","user_nicename":"schoolcontact-test","user_email":                          "test@opteweb.com","user_url":"","user_registered":"2018-01-22 23:09:55",                          "user_activation_key":"","user_status":"0","display_name":"Darren Marshal                          l","spam":"0","deleted":"0"},"ID":26945,"caps":[],"cap_key":"wp_capabilit                          ies","roles":[],"allcaps":[],"filter":null}
```

**Also useful: this is what I get from the wp_options table for roles:**

```
s:13:"administrator";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Administrator";s:12:"capabilities";a:78:{s:13:"switch_themes";b:1;s:11:"edit_themes";b:1;s:16:"activate_plugins";b:1;s:12:"edit_plugins";b:1;s:10:"edit_users";b:1;s:10:"edit_files";b:1;s:14:"manage_options";b:1;    s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:6:"import";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b    :1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:8:"level_10";b:1;s:7:"level_9";b:1;s:7:"level_8";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_other    s_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"d    elete_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_users";b:1;s:12:"create_users";b:1;s:17:"unfiltered_upload";b:1;s    :14:"edit_dashboard";b:1;s:14:"update_plugins";b:1;s:14:"delete_plugins";b:1;s:15:"install_plugins";b:1;s:13:"update_themes";b:1;s:14:"install_themes";b:1;s:11:"update_core";b:1;s:10:"list_users";b:1;s:12:"remove_users";b:1;s:13:"promote_users";b:1;s:18:"    edit_theme_options";b:1;s:13:"delete_themes";b:1;s:6:"export";b:1;s:14:"ts_vcsc_extend";b:1;s:6:"sp_cdm";b:1;s:14:"sp_cdm_vendors";b:1;s:15:"sp_cdm_settings";b:1;s:15:"sp_cdm_projects";b:1;s:15:"sp_cdm_uploader";b:1;s:13:"sp_cdm_addons";b:1;s:14:"sp_cdm_c    lients";b:1;s:11:"sp_cdm_help";b:1;s:12:"sp_cdm_forms";b:1;s:13:"sp_cdm_groups";b:1;s:17:"sp_cdm_categories";b:1;s:15:"sp_cdm_top_menu";b:1;s:26:"sp_cdm_show_folders_as_nav";b:1;s:16:"sp_cdm_user_logs";b:1;s:24:"manage-wp-users-exporter";b:1;s:21:"use-wp-    users-exporter";b:1;}}

s:6:"editor";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Editor";s:12:"capabilities";a:35:{s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:2    0:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pa    ges";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"delet    e_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;s:14:"ts_vcsc_extend";b:1;}}

s:6:"author";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Author";s:12:"capabilities";a:10:{s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:12:"delete_po    sts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;}}

s:11:"contributor";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:11:"Contributor";s:12:"capabilities";a:5:{s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;}}

s:10:"subscriber";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Subscriber";s:12:"capabilities";a:2:{s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;}}

s:14:"school_contact";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:14:"School Contact";s:12:"capabilities";a:3:{s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:13:"manage_school";b:1;}}
```

This is just from the wp_options table, not the wp_xx_options tables from any of the multi-site sites...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it turns out that i was not checking against the good site.
use 
`$user = new WP_User($user_id, '', get_current_blog_id())` and it will be ok.